# default value for textbox in bound form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a data entry form in an MS Access 2010 database which is bound to a table called `CommunicationTable`, which in turn contains a primary key `CommunicationNumber`, a foreign key `ClientNumber`, and a field called `Level`.  When the user opens the form, the `ClientNumber` is automatically populated into a textbox called `ClientNumber`.  I want the `Level` textbox to show a default value equal to the value that was recorded for `Level` in the most recent record (highest `CommunicationNumber` value) for the specified `ClientNumber` in `CommunicationTable`.  How do I set this up?

Here is the code I am currently using in the Default Value expression builder for the `Level` textbox in the form's property sheet:

```
=DLookUp([Level],[CommunicationTable],[CommunicationNumber]=DMax([CommunicationNumber],[CommunicationTable],[ClientNumber]=[Me].[ClientNumber]))
```

This code is giving an empty value when I load the form with a valid `ClientNumber`.  I thought this might be due to the `DMax()` function producing the current (blank) row about to be added to the `CommunicationTable`, but I get the same empty result when I use the following instead:

```
=DLookUp([Level],[CommunicationTable],[CommunicationNumber]=DMax([CommunicationNumber],[CommunicationTable],[ClientNumber]=[Me].[ClientNumber])-1 )
```

How can I change this expression so that it gives the most recent value of Level for the specified `ClientNumber` in `CommunicationTable`?

---

### EDIT:

I tried the following, but it is giving a `#type!` error:

```
=DLookUp("[Level]","[CommunicationTable]","CommunicationNumber= " &  
DMax("CommunicationNumber","[CommunicationTable]","[ClientNumber]=  
" & [Forms]![Main]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![ClientNumber] & ""))
```

Note that the ClientNumber textbox in the form is itself populated using the expression:

```
[Forms]![Main]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![ClientNumber]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you have to adjust your query a bit:

```
=DLookUp("[Level]","[CommunicationTable]","CommunicationNumber= " & DMax("CommunicationNumber","[CommunicationTable]"))
```

Update:

```
=DLookup("[Level]", "[CommunicationTable]", "CommunicationNumber= " & DMax("CommunicationNumber", "[CommunicationTable]", "[ClientNumber]=  " & Me.ClientNumber.Value & ""))
```